# Completion of this proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose

$$\forall m \in \Bbb N : \exists k \in \Bbb N : 5^m +1 =k^3$$

$$\Rightarrow  5^m  = k^3 -1$$

$$ \Rightarrow 5^m = (k -1) (k^2+k +1)$$

Since $5^m$ is a power of 5 both $(k-1)$ and $(k^2+k +1)$  are powers of 5 i.e.

$$5^n = k -1 \tag{1} \text{  for some $n \in \Bbb N$} $$
and 
$$ 5^r = (k^2 +k +1) \text { for  some $r \in \Bbb N $}\tag{2}$$

I know that subtraction of the above is involved in reaching the conclusion that $k$ is a power of 5 and a contradiction

How I believe the following would be  equivalent :
$$(k^2+k+1)= 5^n(k+2) +3$$

Since 3 is not a multiple of 5  therefore $(k^2+k+1)$ is not power of 5, a contradiction.

Is this right? Secondly I am not happy with formatting and language of the proof, any suggestions?

Comment: Does the purpose of you is disproving $\forall m \in \Bbb N : \exists k \in \Bbb N : 5^m +1 =k^3$?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Yes, that is the purpose

Comment: Then, why don't you put $m=1$ and observe that $5^1+1=6$ is not a cube of a integer? The condition is _for all_ $m$.

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Sorry, I am mistaken  I have to show that $5^m +1$ is a not a cube for any natural number

Comment: So, the purpose might be disproving $\exists m \in \Bbb N : \exists k \in \Bbb N : 5^m +1 =k^3$.

Comment: @Matthew: Yours is almost right. Note that $n,r$ are non-negative integers, not natural numbers. This means $n,r$ can be zero. see my answer.

Comment: @mathlove So I consider that case, separately?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, you need to do so. Then yours is just fine. Note that $5^0=1$ cannot be divided by $5$.

Comment: @mathlove that I do know

Comment: @Matthew: OK. Then yours is just fine, again.

Comment: @mathlove BTW, is there a better way of expressing the following: Since $5^m$ is a power of 5 both $(k-1)$ and $(k^2+k +1)$  are powers of 5

Comment: @Matthew: Well, I'm not sure the following is what you want. If $5^m=(k-1)(k^2+k+1)$ holds for $m,k\in\mathbb N$, then there must exist a pair of non-negative integers $(n,r)$ such that $k-1=5^n,k^2+k+1=5^r.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to use $\text{mod}$, then the followings would be simpler.

Note that $n,r$ are non-negative integers such that
$$5^n=k-1,\ 5^r=k^2+k+1.$$
If $n\not =0\ \text{and}\ r\not =0$, then we have in mod $5$
$$k-1\equiv 0\ \text{and}\ k^2+k+1\equiv 0.$$
But, there is no such $k\in\mathbb N$. So, we have '$n=0\ \text{or}\ r=0$'.

If $n=0$, then $k=2$. But there is no $r$ such that $5^r=2^2+2+1=7.$

If $r=0$, then $k=0\ \text{or}\ -1$ which are not natural numbers. Hence, the above leads us to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If you square equation (1) and add 3k you get equation (2), both are divisible by 5, hence k is a multiple of 5, which is not possible.

Comment: What about noticing that $(k^2+k+1) = (k+2) 5^n + 3 $ and $3$ is not a multiple of $5$

Comment: That's even better!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this.

If $k - 1 > 1$, then $5 \mid k-1$ and $5\mid k^2 + k +1$. It follows that $5\mid k^2+2$, the difference between the two. That is,

$$k^2 + 2 \equiv 0\pmod5$$
$$k^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$

But $3$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $5$, hence there are no solutions if $k - 1 > 1$.

The only other case is when $k - 1= 1 \implies k = 2$. Then,

$$5^m = 2^3 - 1$$
$$5^m = 7$$

which clearly has no solutions for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.